# How do I create a dynamic ISBN 13 barcode image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-mvc-3, barcode, isbn

I need to be able to pass in a 13 digit ISBN and have the barcode display as an image on a website dynamically. I have tried some web services at maschup.com and so far unable to get this to render correctly.

Comment: I suggest you phrase your question as a question and place the meat of the solution in your answer. This is permitted/encouraged but you should stick to the question/answer format. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for more details. As it stands, you're likely to be closed as there's no real question.

Comment: Lesson learned, will make sure I do that from now on out. Thanks for the post, and to whomever edited that mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following class to generate ISBN-13 barcodes:

```
public class Bookland : IDisposable {

  public Image BarCode { get; private set; }
  public byte[] BinaryImage {
    get {
      return ms.ToArray();
    } 
  }
  private StringBuilder BinaryText { get; set; }
  private int LineBuffer { get; set; }

private MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

public Bookland(string ISBN) {
  // TODO: Regular Expression Replace all but 0-9
  // TODO: Check Length and Convert 10 to 13 if necessary
  this.BinaryText = new StringBuilder();
  this.LineBuffer = 21;

  char[] isbn = ISBN.ToArray();

  this.BinaryText.Append("101");
  this.CalculateFirstSet(isbn);
  this.BinaryText.Append("01010");
  this.CalculateSecondSet(isbn);
  this.BinaryText.Append("101");

  using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(135, 105, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)) {
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White)) {
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        g.Clear(Color.White);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 72, 10, 15);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawString("9", new Font("Courier", 8), Brushes.Black, r);

        r = new Rectangle(26, 72, 42, 15);
        g.DrawString(ISBN.Substring(1, 6), new Font("Courier", 8), Brushes.Black, r);

        r = new Rectangle(72, 72, 42, 15);
        g.DrawString(ISBN.Substring(7, 6), new Font("Courier", 8), Brushes.Black, r);

        g.Flush();

        char[] binary = this.BinaryText.ToString().ToCharArray();

        int[] delim = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 92, 93, 94 };

        for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i++) {
          pen.Color = binary[i] == '1' ? Color.Black : Color.White;

          if (delim.Contains(i)) {
            g.DrawLine(pen, this.LineBuffer, 20, this.LineBuffer, 85);
          }
          else {
            g.DrawLine(pen, this.LineBuffer, 20, this.LineBuffer, 70);
          }

          this.LineBuffer++;
        }

      }
    }

    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    this.BarCode = Image.FromStream(ms);
  }
}

private void CalculateFirstSet(char[] set) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    switch (set[i]) {
      case '0':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0001101");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0100111");
        }
        break;
      case '1':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0011001");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0110011");
        }
        break;
      case '2':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0010011");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0011011");
        }
        break;
      case '3':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0111101");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0100001");
        }
        break;
      case '4':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0100011");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0011101");
        }
        break;
      case '5':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0110001");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0111001");
        }
        break;
      case '6':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0101111");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0000101");
        }
        break;
      case '7':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0111011");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0010001");
        }
        break;
      case '8':
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0110111");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0001001");
        }
        break;
      default:
        if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6) {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0001011");
        }
        else {
          this.BinaryText.Append("0010111");
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
private void CalculateSecondSet(char[] set) {
  for (int i = 7; i < set.Length; i++) {
    switch (set[i]) {
      case '0':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1110010");
        break;
      case '1':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1100110");
        break;
      case '2':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1101100");
        break;
      case '3':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1000010");
        break;
      case '4':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1011100");
        break;
      case '5':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1001110");
        break;
      case '6':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1010000");
        break;
      case '7':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1000100");
        break;
      case '8':
        this.BinaryText.Append("1001000");
        break;
      default:
        this.BinaryText.Append("1110100");
        break;
    }
  }
}

public void Dispose() {
  this.BarCode.Dispose();
  this.ms.Dispose();
  this.BinaryText = null;
}
```

Here are two examples of its use:

### For Windows Forms

```
using (Bookland isbn = new Bookland(9780495806431) {
  PictureBox.Image = isbn.BarCode();
}
```

### For MVC 3

```
public ActionResult barcode(string id) {
 byte[] isbn = null;

  using (Bookland bookland = new Bookland(id)) {
    isbn = bookland.BinaryImage;
    return File(bookland.BinaryImage, "image/png");
  }
}
```